# DashPlotly : Coarse display of figures on small screen

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am currently working on a data visualization web application with DashPlotly. My goal is to create "stylized" dashboards with DBC. I have a problem with the size of the plotly figures, they are "too zoomed". Indeed, the ideal rendering for me would be the rendering provided with the browser zoomed out to 67%. I attach a GIF to illustrate my point.

I wonder then if it is possible to have a less coarse rendering of plotly figures when the browser is zoomed to 100% ?

I specify that I work on a small screen (laptop 15") and I would like the rendering of the figures to be the same for all types of screens.

For this example I applied a css zoom directly on the DBC card but this is not a viable solution in the long run.

[image]

If someone has already encountered a similar problem, I'm interested ;)

Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem. What happens when you zoom out with the browser is that the font size of the elements in the figure decreases. So I simply reduced the font size of my plotly figures...

```
fig.update_layout(
     font=dict(
         size=12
     )
)
```